# Need to generate random number after time interval

Tags: php, security, random

I'm using my own security form or you can say security challenge question.

But the problem is that I have change that question daily manually.

Is there any way to change it automatically after every 5 minutes?

Here is code of this:

```
if (!$_POST['security_question'] || $_POST['security_question'] != '**PUT HERE YOUR QUESTION?**' ) {
 $errors[] = t('You must answer security question correctly!');
 }
<tr class="row1">
 <td>'.t('Security Question:').'</td>
 <td>**PUT HERE YOUR QUESTION?**

 <input type="text" name="security_question"/>
 </td>
 </tr>
```

So I want to change the link "PUT HERE YOUR QUESTION?" in both case randomly after some time interval.

Comment: I tried to improve your spelling and grammar, not sure what to make of 'froum' though...

Comment: oh sorry for that.. i'm not from english country..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Got The answer and it's working perfectly..!!
Thanks to every one

```
// Create a random number between 0 and 9999 every 5 minutes
function random() {
  $interval = 60*5; // Interval in seconds
  srand(floor(time() / $interval)); 
  echo rand(0, 9999); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would not re-invent the wheel and go for a tried and tested solution such as [reCaptcha](http://www.google.com/recaptcha).

If however, you really must come up with your own solution - as usual there are many answers that could be considered correct.

First of all - if you're using a database, you could store a whole set of security phrases in there and pick one out at random - if using MySQL:

```
SELECT question,answer FROM security_questions ORDER BY RAND();
```

Alternatively, you could simply store a bunch of questions in an array:

```
$myQuestions = array("What is four plus three?", "What is two plus one?");
$myAnswers   = array("7","3");

$random = array_rand($myQuestions);
$rndQuestion = $myQuestions[$random];
$rndAnswer   = $myAnswers[$random];
```

Or you could make one up on the fly if you're using maths questions:

```
$value1 = rand(0,10);
$value2 = rand(0,10);

$question = "What is ".$value1." plus ".$value2."?";
$answer = $value1 + $value2;
```

What you must be very mindful of in all of these situations is coding your page in such a way that a hacker can't get circumvent it, or grab the answer from a HTTP request thats going on in the background etc.

I would still be using reCaptcha :)

Comment: thanks for you answer 
i was also using reCptcha but many spamers used to crack it and spam the site with there links.!!
and ya I triend your solution but i want to create a seperate function for it then to use it..!!
so it's seems to be a trouble for me

Comment: Thnaks gusy for your response i Got the soulution for it using
`function randommmm() {
 srand(floor(time() / (60*60*12)));
    echo rand() % 10000;
 }`

Comment: funny you say that, i've never, ever had a problem with recaptcha letting anyone through that wasn't a valid account.  Its my solution of choice because its never yet let me down!

Comment: it's really not funny.. i also like re-captcha but there are may website wich just creack it for $1 check it on google..