# random number generate in 5 minutes

Tags: php, srand

How can I generate a random number in every 5 minutes? When I searched for it, I found [Need to generate random number after time interval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6662417/need-to-generate-random-number-after-time-interval). Using that, I coded like,

```
    <?
    $seed = floor(time()/(60*60*12));
    srand($seed);
    $item = rand(0,9);
    echo $item;
    ?>
```

But the value of $item is not changing in 5 minute. How can I edit this code?

Comment: I've updated the code in the linked question to clarify for you and other future visitors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The example you pulled from the other SO question generates a new random number every TWELVE HOURS, as indicated by the "12" in your code.

Since you want a new random number every FIVE MINUTES, the code is as follows:

```
<?
$seed = floor(time()/(60*5));
srand($seed);
$item = rand(0,9);
echo $item;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You seed it with the same value for every 12 hour period, which causes it to show the same result. Stop seeding unnecessarily.